# valid input if empty in the javascript

Tags: javascript, input, is-empty

Greeting, I have this input field i want to check if empty then alert with error else I want to call function when submit clicking submit button.

I tried the code below but did not work. any advice?!

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="currency">
<button onclick="convertUstoRiyal()">Convert</button>
<div id="calcAll">the value</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function convertUstoRiyal(amount) {

    var amount = document.getElementById("currency").value;

    if(amount == null){
        alert("please fill the input");
    } else {
        var result = amount * 3.7;
        document.getElementById("calcAll").innerHTML=result;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try `if(amount == ''){`

Comment: I think you should leverage the platform features first. Having a check in code is nice but you can also add the "required" flag on your html element

Comment: thank you man it work you great

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for empty string instead of `null` like `if(amount == '')`

```js
function convertUstoRiyal(amount){
 var amount = document.getElementById("currency").value;
 console.log(amount)
 if(amount == ''){
        alert("please fill the input");
 } else {
   var result = amount * 3.7;
   document.getElementById("calcAll").innerHTML=result;
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="currency">
<button onclick="convertUstoRiyal()">Convert</button>

<div id="calcAll">the value</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're checking `amount == null`. The value that an empty input has by default is `''`, so it should be `amount == ''`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     function convertUstoRiyal() {
       var amount = document.getElementById("currency").value;

       if(amount == null || amount == "") {
          alert("please fill the input");
          return false;
        }else{
          var result = amount * 3.7;
          document.getElementById("calcAll").innerHTML=result;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `null` is also an invalid value, a better check might be `if(amount)`

```
function convertUstoRiyal(amount){
 var amount = document.getElementById("currency").value;
 console.log(amount)
 if(amount){ // HERE
        alert("please fill the input");
 } else {
   var result = amount * 3.7;
   document.getElementById("calcAll").innerHTML=result;
 }
}
```

However, if you need `amount` to always be a numeric and greater than 0, another check might be

```
if(!Number(amount)){
    alert("please enter a valid amount");
}
```

Comment: `amount` is a string, so it will never be `0`. The string `"0"` is not falsey.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Edited. Thanks!

Comment: It can never be null, either.

Comment: IMO `null` check should never be skipped, that's why I left it in. I've faced too many errors like `cannot read property x of null`. Call it a fail-safe.

Comment: If you want to be safe, check if `document.getElementById` returns null.

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertUstoRiyal(){
var amount=document.getElementById("currency").value;
 if(amount =="" || isNaN(amount)){
    alert("please fill the input");
  }else{
var result = amount * 3.7;
    document.getElementById("calcAll").innerHTML=result;
     }
    }
document.getElementById("convert").addEventListener("click",convertUstoRiyal);

//html
 <input type="text" id="currency">
 <button id="convert" >Convert</button>
 <div id="calcAll">the value</div>
```

Comment: What is the result of string * 3.7

Comment: Cause the code it self don’t make this validation so it requires the input to be number

Comment: Is there any function in javascript that say three mean 3 and thirty mean 30 and thirteen mean 13 for example? If not so the input field in this case require only number from the beginning